# c# LinkedIn API dquail Oauth changing from current-status to new <share> api

Tags: c#, api, oauth, linkedin-api

I downloaded the dquail-LinkedinOauth-f169b1f from

https://github.com/dquail/LinkedinOauth

I got it working.  Problem is - this code uses the old current-status api which is deprecated and limited to 140 characters

https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/status-update-api

and has been replaced by the share api which allows 700 characters plus a lot of other features

https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/share-api

I edited the code to provide the new xml and the new URL - but I get an error.  The new code is:

```
    private void btnUpdateStatus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
            //xml += "<current-status>" + txtNewStatus.Text + "</current-status>";
            string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><share>";
            xml += "<comment>" + txtNewStatus.Text + "</comment><visibility><code>anyone</code></visibility></share>";

            //string response = _oauth.APIWebRequest("PUT", "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/current-status", xml);
            string response = _oauth.APIWebRequest("PUT", "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares", xml);
            if (response == "")
                txtResults.Text += "\n\rYour new status updated.  view linkedin for status.";
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            txtResults.Text += "\n\rException: " + exp.Message;
        }

    }
```

The XML I am sending is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
  <share>
  <comment>"Theres a lot of blood, sweat, and guts between dreams and success.", Paul Bryant</comment> 
  <visibility>
  <code>anyone</code> 
  </visibility>
  </share>
```

the error I get is:

"The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using PUT, but the Share API requires POST as the method.

405 means "You're using an HTTP method this endpoint doesn't support"

As far as why, you're not updating the current status, you're adding a new share.
https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/share-api